# Android - Activity need double click to work when resumed

Tags: android, focus, spinner

in my activity, I have a spinner. When I click on it, another activity is started (the main one is not destroyed), in the new activity the user choose a text, press a button and the activity is destroyed, so the old activity is put in the front ( onResume() ) and the text chosen is inserted into the spinner.

The problem is that if I want to do something, i need to click everywhere on the screen one time, then i can press buttons, scroll listviews etc.. If I click buttons (for example), they are not pressed, seems like the activity need to get focus first! I don't understand why so the only thing that i've seen in the LogCat is the warning:

```
Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of...
```

The onClick method of the button in the second activity is this:

```
ActivityOne.stringtoupdate = selection;
finish();
```

This return to the main activity.
The main activity(ActivityOne) set then the new text (stringtoupdate) to the spinner by adding the string to an arraylist and assigning then the arraylist to the spinner's adapter (In the onResume() ).

Which is the problem and how to solve it? Thank you all!

Comment: In your onCLick Method, the if statements used to check the View that is clicked might not be written correctly. Please post your on click method code. We can help you better.

Comment: Which onClick method are you talking about?

Comment: Please post relevant code.

Comment: You are saying that, in your application, in some activity, clicking on button is not responding till you click on the activity. Post the code of that activity class

Comment: Oh, i don't thought it was so important. Anyway, i've updated the question